# ERROR: "Out of global stack" when processing Prolog list of pairs

Tags: prolog

In SWI-Prolog, I have a list whose elements are pairs of the form Key-ValuesList. For instance, one such list may look like:

```
[1-[a,b],2-[],3-[c]]
```

I would like to transform this list into a nested list of pairs of the form Key-[Value], where Value is an element in ValuesList. The above example would be transformed into:

```
[[1-[a],2-[],3-[c]], [1-[b],2-[],3-[c]]]
```

My current solution is the following:

```
% all_pairs_lists(+InputList, -OutputLists).
all_pairs_lists([], [[]]).
all_pairs_lists([Key-[]|Values], CP) :-
  !,
  findall([Key-[]|R], (all_pairs_lists(Values,RCP), member(R,RCP)), CP).
all_pairs_lists([Key-Value|Values], CP) :-
  findall([Key-[V]|R], (all_pairs_lists(Values,RCP), member(V,Value), member(R,RCP)), CP).
```

Using this predicate, a call of the form

```
all_pairs_lists([1-[a,b],2-[],3-[c]],OutputLists).
```

Binds the variable OutputLists to the desired result mentioned above. While it appears correct, this implementation causes an "Out of global stack" error when InputList has very long lists as values.

Is there a less stack consuming approach to doing this? It would seem like quite a common operation for this type of data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to sum it up, you're doing it wrong.

In Prolog, when we want to express a relation instead of a function (several results possible instead of one), we don't use `findall/3` and `member/2` directly. We rather state what the relation is and then maybe once it's done if we need a list of results we use `findall/3`.

Here what it means is that we want to express the following relation:

> Take a list of `Key-Values` and return a list of `Key-[Value]` where `Value` is a member of the `Values` list.

We could do so as follows:

```
% The base case: handle the empty list
a_pair_list([], []).

% The case where the Values list is empty, then the resulting [Value] is []
a_pair_list([Key-[]|List], [Key-[]|Result]) :-
    a_pair_list(List, Result).
% The case where the Values list is not empty, then Value is a member of Values.
a_pair_list([Key-[Not|Empty]|List], [Key-[Value]|Result]) :-
    member(Value, [Not|Empty]),
    a_pair_list(List, Result).
```

Once this relation is expressed, we can already obtain all the info we wish:

```
?- a_pair_list([1-[a, b], 2-[], 3-[c]], Result).
Result = [1-[a], 2-[], 3-[c]] ;
Result = [1-[b], 2-[], 3-[c]] ;
false.
```

The desired list is now just a fairly straight-forward `findall/3` call away:

```
all_pairs_lists(Input, Output) :-
    findall(Result, a_pair_list(Input, Result), Output).
```

The important thing to remember is that it's way better to stay away from extra logical stuff: `!/0`, `findall/3`, etc... because it's often leading to less general programs and/or less correct ones. Here since we can express the relation stated above in a pure and clean way, we should. This way we can limit the annoying use of `findall/3` at the strict minimum.

Comment: Thanks, this really made things clear. However, it still generates the same stack overflow error for large input lists. Five keys with each having a list of 50 values leads to a stack overflow.

Comment: but depending on your specific need it might not be useful to return the list at once. You could look into that too and skip findall entirely.

Comment: btw 5 keys with 50 values each is 312M lists, it's a lot of lists. Even extending the stack will leave other problems there I guess. You need to refer to my previous comment I think

Comment: Yes, you are probably right.. I wasn't anticipating my data structure will get so large, and this probably shows I need to take a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mog already explained clearly what the problem could be, here a version (ab)using of the basic 'functional' builtin for list handling:

```
all_pairs_lists(I, O) :-
    findall(U, maplist(pairs_lists, I, U), O).

pairs_lists(K-[], K-[]) :- !.
pairs_lists(K-L, K-[R]) :- member(R, L).
```

test:

```
?- all_pairs_lists([1-[a,b],2-[],3-[c]],OutputLists).
OutputLists = [[1-[a], 2-[], 3-[c]], [1-[b], 2-[], 3-[c]]].
```

Comment: This version is very nice to look at. Still, just like Mog's version, it leads to a stack overflow for an input having 5 keys and a list of around 50 values each.